# Can I automatically generate a report for each person in my tree using Mac Family Tree?

Tags: macfamilytree

Is it possible to generate and export a report for each person in my family tree? I see how I can view, export and save a snapshot to for later use, but how can I automate the process of creating a report for all individuals in my tree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't look like MacFamilyTree can do a "Person Report" or a "Family Group Report" for all individuals or families.

The best it has in the program is a "List of Persons Report" and a "Marriage List Report", but the information in those reports is limited.

You would need a separate program that can do macros on your Mac in order to automate producing a report for everyone. I'm not a Mac user so I'm not familiar with the macro programs available, but I expect that would be tedious.

Another option is to export to GEDCOM, and import it into another program that can produce the type of report you want.

Answer (score 5):

With MacFamilyTree 7 (release summer 2013) and MacFamilyTree 8 (release spring 2016) it is still not possible to generate individual records for everyone in your database. I don't understand this, since it would provide you backup documents to be stored digitally or as a hardcopy.

OS X has good foundations for automation (Automator, AppleScript, ...) but MacFamilyTree does not take advantage of this. I recommend to use alternative software for generating more advanced records, although I regularly experience problems to import the GEDCOM file generated by MacFamilyTree into third-party software (e.g. GedScape).